# Trim line to the first comma (bash)

Tags: bash, awk, sed, git-bash

I have a line from which I need to cut the branch name to the first comma:

```
commit 2bea9e0351dae65f18d2de11621049b465b1e868 (HEAD, origin/MGB-322, refs/pipelines/36877)
```

I need to cut out `MGB-322`.
The number of characters in a line is always different.
`awk -F "origin/" '{print $2}'` - this is how I cut out

```
MGB-322, refs/pipelines/36877)
```

But how to tell it to trim to the first comma?
I tried doing it via `substr`,

`awk -F "origin/" '{print substr ($2,1, index $2 ,)}'`

But it is not clear how to correctly specify the comma in index

Comment: Only for practice with GNU awk: `awk '{print $2}' FS='[()]' file | awk '{print $2}' FS=', ' | awk '{print $2}' FS='/'`

Comment: A simple `sed` command: `sed 's|.*origin/||; s/,.*//'`

Comment: Rather than filtering, it seems like you could probably apply a format to `git-log` (or whichever tool you're using to generate the string) to get what you want.

Comment: The awk man page is extremely clear on how to specify the comma in index() - `index($2,",")`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With any awk. Use `/` and `,` as field separator:

```
awk '{print $3}' FS='[/,]' file
```

Output:

```
MGB-322
```

---

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Answer (score 1):

***With OP's code fix:*** considered that you have only occurrence of `origin` in case you have more than occurrence then change `$NF` to `$2` in following code. Written and tested in https://ideone.com/xjv2we

```
awk -F"origin/" '{print $NF}' Input_file
```

---

---

`sed` could be also helpful here, generic solution it's based on first occurrence of comma and / as per OP's thread title. I have written this on mobile so couldn't test it as of now should with though and will test it after sometime.

```
sed 's/\([^,]*\),\([^/]*\)\/\(.*\)/\3/' Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

"I need to cut out MGB-322."
You can use `cut` in two steps:

```
echo "${line}" | cut -d"/" -f2 | cut -d"," -f1
```

I would prefer one step with `awk` (already anwered by others) or `sed`

```
echo "${line}" | sed -r 's/.*origin.(.*), refs.*/\1/'
```

Answer (score 1):

Why spawn procs? `bash`'s built-in parameter parsing will handle this.

If

```
$: line="commit 2bea9e0351dae65f18d2de11621049b465b1e868 (HEAD, origin/MGB-322, refs/pipelines/36877)"
```

then

```
$: [[ "$line" =~ .*origin.(.*), ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
MGB-322
```

or maybe

```
$: tmp=${line#*, origin/};  echo ${tmp%,*}
MGB-322
```

or even

```
$: IFS=",/" read _ _ x _ <<< "$line" && echo $x
MGB-322
```

c.f. https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html